# How can I create an index/list of a Google Sites using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

I am using a new Google Site. It has a slew of pages. I want to create a list of all pages/URLs.

I am trying to do this with Google Apps Script. I don't see any Sites API or functions.

Is it possible?